# WebStorm and Typescript fighting over Node16 module resolution absolute imports

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-module-resolution

In order to use the `true-myth` package, I need to switch to `Node16` module resolution, which seems to be unstable in WebStorm, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

No matter what style of imports I use, it seems to produce errors:

Both of these errors are produced by WebStorm:

```js
// TS2307: Cannot find module '@/utils/helpers' or its corresponding type declarations.
import { classNames } from "@/utils/helpers";
```

```js
// TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing '@/utils/helpers.js' instead.
import { classNames } from "@/utils/helpers.ts";
```

When I use `.js`, instead of WebStorm producing an error, the error comes from the application build system/development mode.

```js
// error - ./src/pages/index.tsx:13:0
// Module not found: Can't resolve '@/utils/helpers.js'
import { classNames } from "@/utils/helpers.js";
```

All of these imports disappear when I switch back to `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

Short `tsconfig.json` ([full](https://gist.github.com/213a91990732d8bca1526d8d535e3292))

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
  ]
}
```

For some specifications, this is a `Next.js` project with these versions:

- Windows Pro 10.0.19045 Build 19045
- WebStorm 2022.3.2
- Typescript 4.9.5
- yarn 1.22.19
- next 13.1.1
- Node v18.15.0 & Node v16.19.1 (managed with [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows))

Answer (score 1):

this is expected with your tsconfig.json and typescript @4.9.5, you will see the same issues when running `tsc -p .` in terminal.

- imports without extension:

```
>tsc -p .
src/app.ts:1:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/utils/helpers/foo' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import {helper} from '@/utils/helpers/foo';
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

- with `.ts` extension:

```
>tsc -p .
src/app.ts:1:22 - error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing '@/utils/helpers/foo.js' instead.

1 import {helper} from '@/utils/helpers/foo.ts';
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

the first issue occurs because explicit extension is required when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'., see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#esm-nodejs; the latter is thrown as using `.ts` extension in imports is only supported since typescript@5, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37582

Comment: So what's the fix? Update to Typescript 5?

Comment: In my case, I tried installing `typescript@5` and it sorta solved my problem. I'll need to get used to imports that have the `.js` extension although they are `.ts` files...